# Evaluating *ngIf with observable value inside condition

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I am having difficulty in understanding why using `*ngIf` in below mentioned way throws `Template Parse Error: Parser Error: Missing expected ) at ...`

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="true && (temp$ | async as temp)">
  {{temp}}
</ng-container>
```

Where as refactoring the above code works

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="true">
  <ng-container *ngIf="temp$ | async as temp">
    {{temp}}
  <ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Can I do this without using nested containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is the following (you just need to move the closing parenthesis):

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="true && (temp$ | async) as temp">
  {{temp}}
</ng-container>
```